# How to filter on a foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Site(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

class Team(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    team_member_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
```

I have a view that lists all `team` members in the database:

```
@login_required
def home(request, team_member_id=None):
    team_members = Team.objects.all().order_by('team_member_name')
```

How can I filter this so that only team members who have the same `site` as the `user` that is logged in are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
@login_required
def home(request, team_member_id=None):
    user = request.user
    team_members = Team.objects.all().filter(site__user=user).order_by('team_member_name')
```

Relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter), [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`model relations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) to achieve this.

> To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when
>   you are querying across model relations. That is, the name of the
>   field, followed by a double underscore (__), followed by the name of
>   the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want
>   to join.

In your case, following should work:

`team_members = Team.objects.filter(site__user=user).order_by('team_member_name')`

Answer (score 1):

This can done in single line, but let me explain it so that you can understand the concept:

you can get logged in user from request, as you have used @login_required (user accessing the view will be always logged in)

```
loggedin_user = request.user
```

get user's site:

```
site_of_logged_in_user = Site.objects.get(user=loggedin_user)
# if there can be only one site for a user
```

Now you can get Team by filtering it by site

```
team = Team.objects.filter(site=site_of_logged_in_user)
```